# CFile writing question

Tags: c++, mfc

In my MFC application, I am using CFile class to write data to file. I store a sequence of objects of class CParagraph using Write() method for each data member in order. I use then Read() method to read from file into memory. One of the CParagraph's members used to be of type int, but now I have to change it to size_t, as int cannot hold data large enough. If my application reads a file created before this change, and then a saves a CParagraph object back into the file, size of size_t will be passed to the Write method instead of size of int, so the file will grow. My question is this: can the data written after the object being modified and saved be overwritten and thus corrupted because the object became larger ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  If anything in the file changes size, everything after it must be re-saved.

It's common to save a "version" char as the first part of a file.  Then, when you need to resize a variable (or change tons of things), you can change the version when saving.  Then, while loading, you can check the version, and use the coresponding code to load it.  Then you can still open files from older versions.  Note that this version should only change when the file format changes, not when you rebuild/release.

Comment: I hate that my answer is so short, but I honestly couldn't think of anything more to say. :(  I could put in code, but nothing that would help.

Comment: You might want to address file version compatibility. Can the new MFC application still read the old files? In practice, this is a real problem for widely used programs. People don't like it if all their old files are suddenly unusable. Heck even when people migrated from WordPerfect to MS Word they still expected to use their old files.

Comment: Yes, I added a check for file version, so in case of an old file, I pass sizeof(int), otherwise sizeof(myVariable).